# How to vertically align a video in the middle of a cell?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to align a video in the middle of a fixed height cell, in a way that the overflow at the top and bottom is hidden.

Up to now i've got:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="150" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <video autoplay loop width="100%" style="display: block;">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However the "vertical-align: middle;" in the "td" doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm looking to see only the middle 150 pixels, but currently it's showing the top 150...

For anyone who is able to help, a link to my JSfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/xtxkm02a/1/

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `display: block` from your `td` and insert a div with overflow hidden. With `display: block` you have overwritten the `display: table-cell`.

Comment: never use tables for layout, tables are for tabular data only

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, additional to my comment.

```css
table {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  overflow: hidden; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 30px;
}
.video {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
}
.video video {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -75px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="center" style="">
            <div class="video">
                <video loop>
                    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Phil, thanks for taking a look at my issue. I've tried your code but still don't quite get the result i'm looking for. When the video loads, it is still showing the top portion of the frame, I cant get it to show me the middle section of the video.

Comment: My fault. I haven't read the question correctly. I have updated my answer and now the video is centered. You need a height on the outer div and a negative margin top with the outer div height / 2